# Is the Berlin Wall Section on the Sakharov Grounds Accessible at Night?

Tags: russia, landmarks, moscow, scams, parks-and-gardens

I am informed that the only *known* section of the Berlin Wall situated in Russia is on the grounds of the [Andrei Sakharov Center](http://www.russianmuseums.info/M1623).  The centre itself is composed of his former residence and a 'largish' park roughly 1/3 of a mile from Red Square.

As shown, this section of the wall is mounted outside of the centre:

[image: Berlin Wall - http://en.the-wall-net.org/moscow-rus/]

(Previous image taken out as it was replaces by spam on the host site.)

**Question**:  Is this area of the park accessible at night?

Or alternatively, I am also aware that the centre has been facing some [draconian measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_foreign_agent_law) laid down by the less tolerant regime in Russia.  So if the grounds are open after the centre's closing time of 19:00, is a visitor likely to be challenged by the police for identification and questioning?  I have no problems communicating and have all the necessary paperwork to meet any night time challenge by the authorities, but I will be on a tight schedule and would not have extra time for that kind of thing.

Finally, if I am questioned by the police is there an easy way to tell that it's not a scam by people *impersonating* the police?

---

Semi-related: [How can I see the Berlin Wall?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20779/how-can-i-see-the-berlin-wall)

Comment: It looks like it's in "Garden Square/The Sakharov Museum", a bit west of the Sakhalin Museum. There are no fences and it's near a sidewalk that short-cuts the corner so you could always say that you're just walking through. See this [Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7511276,37.6570355,3a,75y,232.5h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-i5GZpaai6QY%2FVPc3NHNkiTI%2FAAAAAAAANTg%2FlD1k8dc96bcMfaOQmnv0tQxD9540tD8rw!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2F-i5GZpaai6QY%2FVPc3NHNkiTI%2FAAAAAAAANTg%2FlD1k8dc96bcMfaOQmnv0tQxD9540tD8rw%2Fw203-h101-n-k-no%2F!7i10240!8i5120!6m1!1e1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google [streetview](https://www.google.com/maps/@55.7508925,37.6571356,3a,75y,359.22h,74.97t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sEp1AN1spxwRbARDeHrZcBw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) shows the wall segment here:

[image]

Source: google maps

An aerial view of the location:

[image]

Source: google maps

It can be seen that there is no gating or railings and the wall segment is on a public road with legal parking:

[image]

Source: google maps

> Question: Is this area of the park accessible at night?
>   [I]s a visitor
>   likely to be challenged by the police for identification and
>   questioning?

**Update**: I contacted the author of the spottedbylocals post below, who has visited the park, and she confirmed that the place is open 24 hours.

From the above pictures you can see that the wall section is accessible at all times and a short viewing at night would not be remarkable on a public path and would give no more cause for concern to the police than a visitor walking elsewhere in Moscow at night.

An article on the Sakharov park in the evening can be found [here](http://www.spottedbylocals.com/moscow/sakharov-centre-public-park/).

> When evening falls, the area is illuminated with modern streetlights.
>   But personally I’m fond of the squared clock which also becomes a
>   lantern once it’s dark outside. Many people sit here, having a snack,
>   or just talking.

With an image of what you might expect to see after dusk:

[spottedbylocals.com http://upload.spottedbylocals.com/Moscow/small/sakharov-centre-public-park-moscow-(by-maria-selezneva).jpg](http://upload.spottedbylocals.com/Moscow/small/sakharov-centre-public-park-moscow-(by-maria-selezneva).jpg)

Source: spottedbylocals.com (external link from above article)

Since you won't be visiting the museum, you might like to take a [virtual tour](http://www.wiriworlds.com/Michael/sakharov/) of the museum. Another view of the wall section is available on the tour:

[image]

Source: wiriworlds.com (external link)

> Finally, if I am questioned by the police is there an easy way to tell
>   that it's not a scam by people impersonating the police?

A search for news articles relating to police impersonation in Moscow in particular and Russia in general does not show any cause for concern.

According to this [article](http://blog.transparency.org/2012/06/13/can-i-see-your-badge-officer/) Russian police should carry one of these [badges](http://ria.ru/infografika/20110805/412408476.html):

[image: sample image]

Source: ria.ru external link from above article

Should you still be concerned and you feel it is safe to make a phone call, a list of emergency numbers is available [here](https://www.angloinfo.com/russia/how-to/russia-healthcare-emergencies). The Moscow city police number is (495) 200 9305

Finally, regarding the *Foreign agent law* crackdown, the fine against the Sakharov Center was recently [cancelled](http://www.rferl.org/content/russia-sakharov-center-ruling-fine-cancelled/27644492.html).

> The Moscow City Court has canceled a lower court's decision to fine
>   the Moscow-based Sakharov Center for not complying with a
>   controversial "foreign agents" law.